# Limit the number of characters in a Rich text editor

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I want to limit the number of characters in a html jquery rich text editor using jquery.The max limit is 1000 characters.I can only add data into it if i delete some characters from it.Even copy paste from context menu should not work after reaching the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Javascript code:-

```
function checkBox(){if(document.getElementById("**ELEMENT NAME**").value.length>1000){document.getElementById("**ELEMENT NAME**").value = document.getElementById("**ELEMENT NAME**").value.substring(0, 1000);}}
window.setInterval("checkBox();", 1000);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works for simple text editors and not for html jquery editors

Comment: It will still work if you are using JQuery without fail! Anyways, always there to help! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is not jQuery, but it will do the trick

<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
      function limitText() {
        var txtArea = document.myForm.myTextArea;
        if (txtArea.value.length > 1000) {
            txtArea.value = txtArea.value.substring(0, 999);
        }
     }
   -->
   </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myForm">
       <textarea name="myTextArea" rows=2 cols=50 onChange='limitText()'>
         Here is some text in my text area.
       </textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
```